# SQL Switch asignando valor a una variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, cast

Necesito recorrer una tabla completa y dependiendo de su contenido insertar esos datos en otra parte eso me imagine que podía utilizar un **switch**, pero tengo problemas para referenciarlo a la variable que quiero.
Necesito reconocer el valor de [Cargo/Abono] y dependiendo si es "-" ó "+" guardarla [Importe] en variable  `@abono` o `@cargo`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stats_ddl') is not null DROP TABLE stats_ddl

GO
CREATE TABLE #stats_ddl (
[Cuenta] varchar(max),
[Fecha] varchar(50), --
[Hora] varchar(50),
[Suc] varchar(50),
[Descripcio] varchar(max),
[Cargo/Abono] varchar(50),
[Importe] varchar(50),
[Saldo] varchar(50),
[Referencia] varchar(50),
[Concepto / Referencia Interbancaria] varchar(max) --
);
Go 

declare @cargo varchar(max) = '',
@count int = 0,
@abono varchar(max) = ''

bulk insert erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl
from 'C:\SAM\SamFinanzas\Facturas\3_20180822144927\3_20180822144927.csv'
with (          firstrow = 2,                
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

--select * from   stats_ddl

declare @count int = 0,
  @countb int = 1
set @count = (select count( * ) from #stats_ddl)
while @countb <= @count
begin
    DECLARE @fechaMov VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) [Cargo/Abono] FROM     #stats_ddl);
    PRINT 'fecha' + @fechaMov + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @count);

-- por quiero meter el switch y que me tome cargo/abono y dependiendo de lo que sea me almacene en cargo u abono la columa de importe
    DELETE TOP (1) FROM #stats_ddl
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #stats_ddl;
end
```

[image: Esta es mi tabla]

Comment: En todo caso deberías hacer algo así `select @abono = cast(case .... end) from ...`, fijate además que te falta el `end` del `case`, y por otro lado, tienes claro que `@abono` es una variable escalar y solo puede albergar uno solo de los valores independientemente de la cantidad de filas que tengas? Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo necesitas para tu query es agregar esto, desde un case no estoy muy seguro que puedas setear valores a múltiples variables de la manera que quieres hacerlo:

```
DECLARE @Importe VARCHAR(50), 
        @CargoAbono VARCHAR(50);
SELECT TOP(1) @CargoAbono = [Cargo/Abono], @Importe = [Importe] FROM #stats_ddl
IF @CargoAbono LIKE '%+%'
BEGIN
    SET @abono = @Importe
END
IF @CargoAbono LIKE '%-%'
BEGIN
    SET @cargo = @Importe
END
```